# Selecionar Owner via URL - FastAPI

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Estou com um projeto em desenvolvimento onde o banco é separado por alguns Schemas. Os schemas "aleatórios", falo isso pois eles não tem um padrão para serem criados, pois se tivesse eu só incluiria no meu model.py e tudo resolvido.

**main.py**

```
import socket
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Generator, Dict, List
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, HTTPException, status
from config import Base, SessionLocal, engine
from sqlalchemy.engine.base import Connection
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

import schemas
import models

app = FastAPI()

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

@app.get("/")
async def alive():
    #get_db()
    return {"API": "HUBSales",
            "versão": "v1.0",
            "servidor": socket.gethostname(),
            "data": datetime.now().strftime("%c")}

############## LISTA TODOS OS CLIENTES ##############
@app.get("/tenant/")
async def busca(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return db.query(models.TenantModel).all()
    
############## VALIDAÇÃO TENANT ##############
@app.get("/{tenant}/login/{usuario}_{senha}", status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def validaUsuario(tenant: str, usuario: str, senha: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):

        **Aqui devo desenvolver o código para a validação, utilizando o campo TENANT
          que é o Schema que irá ser utilizado nas pesquisas**
```

**models.py**

```
from config import Base, engine, metadata
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, Float, schema, ARRAY

class TenantModel(Base):
    __table__ = Table('TENANT', metadata, autoload_with = engine)
    __mapper_args__ = { 'primary_key':[__table__.c.pktenant] }

class UsuariosModel(Base):
    __table__ = Table('USUARIOS', metadata, autoload_with = engine)
    __mapper_args__ = { 'primary_key':[__table__.c.pkusuario] }
```

Comment: E o problema é ...

Comment: O problema é saber como eu posso fazer isso. Já tentei algumas formas, como criar uma variável em model.py para passar o owner mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido inserindo o código abaixo nas querys:

```
db.connection(execution_options={ "schema_translate_map": { 'schema': novo_schema}})
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).